# Looking for App Engine Channel Api Java replacement solution for AngularJS client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, angularjs, channel-api, pubnub

We are developing an `AngularJS` + `App Engine Java` app and would like to use some real time push technology. App Engine push technology called Channel API is a pain to manage and I'd like to know what others are using and how successful they are using it.

Basic need: From App Engine Java backend (running java only, no nodejs available) the server pushes real time updates to the `AngularJS` web clients.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Channel API + using polling as a backup.

Other alternatives will involve running a 3rd party (non-app engine) push service.  This could be either something you set up yourself on another server (ie Amazon, Heroku or Google Compute Engine) or a service provider like pusher.com or beaconpush.com

There isn't another real alternative on App Engine.

Comment: Hi, In case i need to push messages from my app engine application to other java stand alone application , how can i achieve it? I tried using Java ScriptEngine, but It doesn't recognize Channel api Java script notations. any suggestions would be a real help...Thank you in advance